# icon on toggle not changing html css jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, accordion

accordion icon not changing with this code..

```js
$('.toggle-title').click(function(){
      $(this).next('div').siblings('div').slideUp('slow');
      $(this).next('.toggle-details').slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

```css
.toggle-item {margin-bottom: 20px;border-radius: 3px;}
.toggle-item .toggle-title {position: relative;cursor: pointer;background: #f2f0f0;border-radius: 3px;padding: 21px;border: 1px solid #e9d07b;border-collapse: collapse;margin-bottom: 20px;}
.toggle-item .toggle-title h2 {margin:0;font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Book';font-size: 24px;color:#494949;max-width: 90%;}
.toggle-item .toggle-title:before{content: '\f101';font-family: 'FontAwesome';position: absolute;right: 50px;top: 18px;color:#237c62;font-size: 22px;font-weight: 900;}
.toggle-item .toggle-title.clicked:before{content: '\f103';font-family: 'FontAwesome';position: absolute;right: 50px;top: 18px;color:#237c62;}
.toggle-item .toggle-details {display: none;background: transparent;padding: 21px;margin-top: 20px;border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;}
.toggle-item .toggle-details p {font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Book';color: #797979;font-size: 18px;font-weight: 600;line-height: 1.5;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-item">
     <section class="toggle-title">
       <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2>
     </section>
     <div class="toggle-details">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
    </div>
<section class="toggle-title">
       <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2>
     </section>
     <div class="toggle-details">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yea you may want to explain what exactly isn't working. it works fine for me here...https://jsfiddle.net/2zoufrn9/

Comment: i want the icon to change to downwards.. thanks

Comment: please someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Css :**

```
.toggle-item .toggle-title:before{content: '\25B6';font-family: 'FontAwesome';position: absolute;right: 50px;top: 18px;color:#237c62;font-size: 22px;font-weight: 900;}

.toggle-item .toggle-title.clicked:before{content: '\25BD';font-family: 'FontAwesome';position: absolute;right: 50px;top: 18px;color:#237c62;font-size: 22px;font-weight: 900;}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.toggle-title').click(function(){
      $('.toggle-title').not(this).removeClass('clicked'); <-----Added
      $(this).toggleClass('clicked');<-----------------------------Added
      $(this).next('div').siblings('div').slideUp('slow');
      $(this).next('.toggle-details').slideToggle( "slow" );
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.toggle-title').click(function(){
      $('.toggle-title').not(this).removeClass('clicked');
      $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
      $(this).next('div').siblings('div').slideUp('slow');
      $(this).next('.toggle-details').slideToggle( "slow" );
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle-item {margin-bottom: 20px;border-radius: 3px;}
.toggle-item .toggle-title {position: relative;cursor: pointer;background: #f2f0f0;border-radius: 3px;padding: 21px;border: 1px solid #e9d07b;border-collapse: collapse;margin-bottom: 20px;}
.toggle-item .toggle-title h2 {margin:0;font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Book';font-size: 24px;color:#494949;max-width: 90%;}
.toggle-item .toggle-details {display: none;background: transparent;padding: 21px;margin-top: 20px;border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;}
.toggle-item .toggle-details p {font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Book';color: #797979;font-size: 18px;font-weight: 600;line-height: 1.5;}

.toggle-item .toggle-title:before{content: '\25B6';font-family: 'FontAwesome';position: absolute;right: 50px;top: 18px;color:#237c62;font-size: 22px;font-weight: 900;}

.toggle-item .toggle-title.clicked:before{content: '\25BD';font-family: 'FontAwesome';position: absolute;right: 50px;top: 18px;color:#237c62;font-size: 22px;font-weight: 900;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-item">
     <section class="toggle-title">
       <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2>
     </section>
     <div class="toggle-details">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
    </div>
<section class="toggle-title">
       <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2>
     </section>
     <div class="toggle-details">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry. still the icon is wrong when other option is clicked. the icon remains downwards

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery toggle class

```js
$('.toggle-title').click(function(){
  $(this).next('div').siblings('div').slideUp('slow');
  $(this).next('.toggle-details').slideToggle( "slow" );
  $(this).toggleClass( "clicked" );
});
```

```css
.toggle-item {margin-bottom: 20px;border-radius: 3px;}
.toggle-item .toggle-title {position: relative;cursor: pointer;background: #f2f0f0;border-radius: 3px;padding: 21px;border: 1px solid #e9d07b;border-collapse: collapse;margin-bottom: 20px;}
.toggle-item .toggle-title h2 {margin:0;font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Book';font-size: 24px;color:#494949;max-width: 90%;}
.toggle-item .toggle-title:before{content: '\f101';font-family: 'FontAwesome';position: absolute;right: 50px;top: 18px;color:#237c62;font-size: 22px;font-weight: 900;}
.toggle-item .toggle-title.clicked:before{content: '\f103';font-family: 'FontAwesome';position: absolute;right: 50px;top: 18px;color:#237c62;}
.toggle-item .toggle-details {display: none;background: transparent;padding: 21px;margin-top: 20px;border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;}
.toggle-item .toggle-details p {font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Book';color: #797979;font-size: 18px;font-weight: 600;line-height: 1.5;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-item">
     <section class="toggle-title">
       <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2>
     </section>
     <div class="toggle-details">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="toggle-item">
     <section class="toggle-title">
       <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2>
     </section>
     <div class="toggle-details">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it work at first but if i click on other option, the icon wont get back at sidewards

Comment: yeah, it works if you click the same option,try adding another toggle item and toggle details.. thank you for the help

Comment: Do not merge the toggle title and toogle details to existing toggle item div. Add new toggle item div.  It works fine if you do so.

Comment: if i do so, the other option will not automatically close.. i need it bro automaticcaly closing/hiding,, thanks always

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.toggle-title').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
      $(this).next('div').siblings('div').slideUp('slow');
      $(this).next('.toggle-details').slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

```css
.toggle-item {margin-bottom: 20px;border-radius: 3px;}
.toggle-item .toggle-title {position: relative;cursor: pointer;background: #f2f0f0;border-radius: 3px;padding: 21px;border: 1px solid #e9d07b;border-collapse: collapse;margin-bottom: 20px;}
.toggle-item .toggle-title h2 {margin:0;font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Book';font-size: 24px;color:#494949;max-width: 90%;}
.toggle-item .toggle-title:before{content: '\f101';font-family: 'FontAwesome';position: absolute;right: 50px;top: 18px;color:#237c62;font-size: 22px;font-weight: 900;}
.toggle-item .toggle-title.clicked:before{content: '\f103';font-family: 'FontAwesome';position: absolute;right: 50px;top: 18px;color:#237c62;}
.toggle-item .toggle-details {display: none;background: transparent;padding: 21px;margin-top: 20px;border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;}
.toggle-item .toggle-details p {font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Book';color: #797979;font-size: 18px;font-weight: 600;line-height: 1.5;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-item">
     <section class="toggle-title">
       <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2>
     </section>
     <div class="toggle-details">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please use the following script:

```
$('.toggle-title').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked'); //added line
  $(this).next('div').siblings('div').slideUp('slow');
  $(this).next('.toggle-details').slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

Comment: it work but if i click on other option, the icon wont get back at sidewards

Comment: Which other option do you mean?

Comment: yeah, it works if you click the same option,try adding another toggle item and toggle details.. thank you for the help